# Array to readable data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am getting who is data, so have code like as bellow

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$query = $_GET['query'];
$fast = $_GET['fast'];
include_once('whois.main.php');
include_once('whois.utils.php');
$whois = new Whois();
$result = $whois->Lookup($query);
?>
```

here i can see my dump data by

```
<?php
echo '<pre>'; // This is for correct handling of newlines
ob_start();
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

after that my dump data look like this

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Access to .IN WHOIS information is provided to assist persons in determining the contents of a domain name registration record in the .IN registry database. The data in this record is provided by .IN Registry for informational purposes only, and .IN does not guarantee its accuracy.  This service is intended only for query-based access. You agree that you will use this data only for lawful purposes and that, under no circumstances will you use this data to(a) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission by e-mail, telephone, or facsimile of mass unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations to entities other than the data recipient's own existing customers; or (b) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes that send queries or data to the systems of Registry Operator, a Registrar, or Afilias except as reasonably necessary to register domain names or modify existing registrations. All rights reserved. .IN reserves the right to modify these terms at any time. By submitting this query, you agree to abide by this policy.
    [1] => 
    [2] => Domain ID:D9115931-AFIN
    [3] => Domain Name:WHOISEXTRACTOR.IN
    [4] => Created On:17-Jan-2015 19:27:40 UTC
    [5] => Last Updated On:29-Sep-2015 19:29:09 UTC
    [6] => Expiration Date:17-Jan-2016 19:27:40 UTC
    [7] => Sponsoring Registrar:GoDaddy.com, LLC (R101-AFIN)
    [8] => Status:CLIENT DELETE PROHIBITED
    [9] => Status:CLIENT RENEW PROHIBITED
    [10] => Status:CLIENT TRANSFER PROHIBITED
    [11] => Status:CLIENT UPDATE PROHIBITED
    [12] => Registrant ID:CR185387971
    [13] => Registrant Name:Shiv Singh Kushwaha
    [14] => Registrant Organization:
    [15] => Registrant Street1:Village and Post - Bargarh
    [16] => Registrant Street2:
    [17] => Registrant Street3:
    [18] => Registrant City:Chitrakoot
    [19] => Registrant State/Province:Uttar Pradesh
    [20] => Registrant Postal Code:210208
    [21] => Registrant Country:IN
    [22] => Registrant Phone:+91.9450987150
    [23] => Registrant Phone Ext.:
    [24] => Registrant FAX:
    [25] => Registrant FAX Ext.:
    [26] => Registrant Email:support@whoisextractor.in
    [27] => Admin ID:CR185387973
    [28] => Admin Name:Shiv Singh Kushwaha
    [29] => Admin Organization:
    [30] => Admin Street1:Village and Post - Bargarh
    [31] => Admin Street2:
    [32] => Admin Street3:
    [33] => Admin City:Chitrakoot
    [34] => Admin State/Province:Uttar Pradesh
    [35] => Admin Postal Code:210208
    [36] => Admin Country:IN
    [37] => Admin Phone:+91.9450987150
    [38] => Admin Phone Ext.:
    [39] => Admin FAX:
    [40] => Admin FAX Ext.:
    [41] => Admin Email:support@whoisextractor.in
    [42] => Tech ID:CR185387972
    [43] => Tech Name:Shiv Singh Kushwaha
    [44] => Tech Organization:
    [45] => Tech Street1:Village and Post - Bargarh
    [46] => Tech Street2:
    [47] => Tech Street3:
    [48] => Tech City:Chitrakoot
    [49] => Tech State/Province:Uttar Pradesh
    [50] => Tech Postal Code:210208
    [51] => Tech Country:IN
    [52] => Tech Phone:+91.9450987150
    [53] => Tech Phone Ext.:
    [54] => Tech FAX:
    [55] => Tech FAX Ext.:
    [56] => Tech Email:support@whoisextractor.in
    [57] => Name Server:NS2.WHOISEXTRACTOR.IN
    [58] => Name Server:NS1.WHOISEXTRACTOR.IN
    [59] => Name Server: 
    [60] => Name Server: 
    [61] => Name Server: 
    [62] => Name Server: 
    [63] => Name Server: 
    [64] => Name Server: 
    [65] => Name Server: 
    [66] => Name Server: 
    [67] => Name Server: 
    [68] => Name Server: 
    [69] => Name Server: 
    [70] => DNSSEC:Unsigned
    [71] => 
    [72] => 
)
```

so have created a `foreach` loop but its not working, my code is

```
<?php foreach ($result['regrinfo'] as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value['rawdata'];
}
?>
```

But i have need it on formatted like.

```
Domain Name: SRAPSWARE.COM
Registry Domain ID: 1628686810_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.publicdomainregistry.com
Registrar URL: www.publicdomainregistry.com
Updated Date: 2015-12-05T05:37:38Z
Creation Date: 2010-12-04T10:08:59Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2016-12-04T11:08:59Z
Registrar: PDR Ltd. d/b/a PublicDomainRegistry.com
Registrar IANA ID: 303
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Registry Registrant ID: 
Registrant Name: Domain Admin
Registrant Organization: Privacy Protection Service INC d/b/a PrivacyProtect.org
Registrant Street: C/O ID#10760, PO Box 16 Note - Visit PrivacyProtect.org to contact the domain owner/operator Note - Visit PrivacyProtect.org to contact the domain owner/operator  
Registrant City: Nobby Beach
Registrant State/Province: Queensland
Registrant Postal Code: QLD 4218
Registrant Country: AU
Registrant Phone: +45.36946676
Registrant Phone Ext: 
Registrant Fax: 
Registrant Fax Ext: 
Registrant Email: contact@privacyprotect.org
Registry Admin ID: 
Admin Name: Domain Admin
Admin Organization: Privacy Protection Service INC d/b/a PrivacyProtect.org
Admin Street: C/O ID#10760, PO Box 16 Note - Visit PrivacyProtect.org to contact the domain owner/operator Note - Visit PrivacyProtect.org to contact the domain owner/operator  
Admin City: Nobby Beach
Admin State/Province: Queensland
Admin Postal Code: QLD 4218
Admin Country: AU
Admin Phone: +45.36946676
Admin Phone Ext: 
Admin Fax: 
Admin Fax Ext: 
Admin Email: contact@privacyprotect.org
Registry Tech ID: 
Tech Name: Domain Admin
Tech Organization: Privacy Protection Service INC d/b/a PrivacyProtect.org
Tech Street: C/O ID#10760, PO Box 16 Note - Visit PrivacyProtect.org to contact the domain owner/operator Note - Visit PrivacyProtect.org to contact the domain owner/operator  
Tech City: Nobby Beach
Tech State/Province: Queensland
Tech Postal Code: QLD 4218
Tech Country: AU
Tech Phone: +45.36946676
Tech Phone Ext: 
Tech Fax: 
Tech Fax Ext: 
Tech Email: contact@privacyprotect.org
Name Server: ns1.srapsware.com
Name Server: ns2.srapsware.com
DNSSEC:Unsigned
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse-contact@publicdomainregistry.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1-2013775952
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
>>>Last update of WHOIS database: 2015-12-09T06:41:04+0000Z<<<
For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp

Registration Service Provided By: RURALSERVER

PRIVACYPROTECT.ORG is providing privacy protection services to this domain name to 
protect the owner from spam and phishing attacks. PrivacyProtect.org is not 
responsible for any of the activities associated with this domain name. If you wish 
to report any abuse concerning the usage of this domain name, you may do so at 
http://privacyprotect.org/contact. We have a stringent abuse policy and any 
complaint will be actioned within a short period of time.

The data in this whois database is provided to you for information purposes 
only, that is, to assist you in obtaining information about or related to a 
domain name registration record. We make this information available "as is",
and do not guarantee its accuracy. By submitting a whois query, you agree 
that you will use this data only for lawful purposes and that, under no 
circumstances will you use this data to: 
(1) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes that stress or load 
this whois database system providing you this information; or 
(2) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass unsolicited, 
commercial advertising or solicitations via direct mail, electronic mail, or 
by telephone. 
The compilation, repackaging, dissemination or other use of this data is 
expressly prohibited without prior written consent from us. The Registrar of 
record is PDR Ltd. d/b/a PublicDomainRegistry.com. 
We reserve the right to modify these terms at any time. 
By submitting this query, you agree to abide by these terms.
```

so please help me to get formatted data

Comment: Your `ob_start()` has no closing `ob_flush()`, maybe this is the problem...

Comment: I am not getting you please post entire array

Comment: What is the output from `echo $value['rawdata'];`

Comment: *"after that my dump data look like this"* - no, that is not what a `var_dump` result would look like. I also don't see where your "want" and your "have" differs.

Comment: array output can be see here http://66.23.231.202/whois/index2.php?query=srapsware.com&output=normal

Comment: Oh, you meant us to *click* on that link?! Why don't you post that data here?!

Comment: that data is too long stackoverflow not accepting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `$value['rawdata']` is another array, it should be

```
<?php 

foreach ($result['rawdata'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . '<br>';

    /* 
        in $key are keys 0-77, in $value are strings

        output:
        'Domain Name: SRAPSWARE.COM'
        'Registry Domain ID: '
        ...
    */
}

?>
```

Comment: Not working its show error **Warning**: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/hostingsp/public_html/whois/index2.php on line 65

Comment: @srapsware: sorry, `rawdata` is in the same level as `regrinfo` - I make that on base of your question. It has to be `$result['rawdata']`, I've updated my answer. `$result['regrinfo']` is one array, `$result['rawdata']` the second one. I don't want what data you exactly need.

Answer (score 2):

[srapsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2384642/srapsware) YOU have to use this

```
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
         {
            echo $value;
               OR
            echo $result[$key];

          }
```

Comment: can you post result of print_r($result) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the result array like below-

```
<?php
if(!empty($result['rawdata']))
    {
        $winfo .= '<pre>'.implode($result['rawdata'],"\n").'</pre>';
    }
    else
    {
        $winfo = implode($whois->Query['errstr'],"\n<br></br>");
    }   
    echo $winfo;
?>
```

Please use this and let us know the result..Also plz refresh 2-3 times as the library u r using is not giving result in one attempt. If you want i can give you another solution.

You can check this on this url

http://easywebtricks.com/demo/phpwhois/whois.php?query=srapsware.com&output=normal

OR can use another solution of this url

http://easywebtricks.com/demo/whois/